# Alert dialog buttons problems in Android L

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-alertdialog

I have created a AlertDialog in my app. Before Android L AlertDialog buttons fit in dialog box, but in Android L buttons label automatically converts in title case and buttons not fit in dialog box.
Please see screenshots:

Android L:
 [image: Android L AlertDialog screenshot]

Android Kitkat:

[image: Android 4.4 AlertDialog screenshot]

Is anybody see this issue. Can any help me to solve this problem, although this is latest android version.

**Code**: (I have not used xml code to create dialog, here is java code:)

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle(R.string.feedback_label);
        alert.setMessage(msgStrId);
        alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.close_label, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
        alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.rate_app, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
        alert.setNeutralButton(R.string.feedback_label,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
        alert.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
        alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: post your custom alert dialog xml..

Comment: @MSGadag Please see code.

Comment: Have you got any solutions, yet? Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I know, I am too late. But I share my suggestion here. Maybe it will be helpful.

```
  AlertDialog alertDialog  = alert.create();
    alertDialog .show();
    alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setAllCaps(false);
    alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setAllCaps(false);
    alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL).setAllCaps(false);
 alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: A great answer can be written years after a question was asked.

Comment: Sorry sir , I could not understand, will you guide?

Comment: I meant: an answer is not necessarily "too late" just because the question is old.

Comment: this is a working solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893840/lollipop-capitalizes-buttons-text-in-my-app/39143743#39143743

Answer (score 6):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="MyAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

A slight modification to @Kush's answer. You don't have to call `dialog.show()` multiple times.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Title");
        builder.setMessage("message");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Do Something
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
       dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setAllCaps(false);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it will works For You.
https://github.com/drakeet/MaterialDialog

Answer (score -2):

If you will try to find solution for this then you might get but also for small screens you will stuck again and you need to find something for it also.

So better is divide your string so it will resolve your issue for any screen.

For that follow below code.

Go to strings.xml file. and change your title as below.

```
 <string name="rate_app">Rate This \n App</string>
 <string name="feedback_label">Report \n Issues</string>
```

If "\n" not work then user 
 tag. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -4):

Use `<item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>` in the definition of your application theme. Then all dialogs in the application are no more uppercase.

Comment: The issue is not that the dialog is not uppercase, but that the buttons do not fit inside the dialog box.