# Android how to make ok button on dialog not all caps

Tags: java, android

For an alert dialog in Android, how do you make the positive button not have all capital letters. The text is "OK" instead of "Ok".

Comment: What kind of dialog are you using?  Please show your code if you want a proper answer.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 Um... I said alert dialog if you read the question?

Comment: Yes, that is why I'm confused.  You set the text yourself.  There are no default options.

Comment: this is a working solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893840/lollipop-capitalizes-buttons-text-in-my-app/39143743#39143743

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it to be anything you want  - Eg.:

```
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Title");
        builder.setMessage("message");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                return;
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
```

Reference: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setPositiveButton(int, android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setPositiveButton(int,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener))

Comment: No problem. When in doubt, double check the documentation - which can be done online or from your IDE! Also, posting the code you are trying to get work always helps us direct your/our efforts better!

Comment: this thing is not gonna work on lolipop and version greater than it.

Comment: As in, should be a Snack bar ?

Comment: Starting with Android 5.0, Buttons automatically have their text capitalized.  you can't set capitaliztion in builder directly.

Answer (score 22):

The accepted solution above won't work in Lollipop and above. Here's the working solution.

After showing the dialog, I'm setting the button all caps false. Make sure you do it after `dialog.show()`. Else, you'll get `Null Pointer Exception`.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Title");
        builder.setMessage("message");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Do Something
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
       dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setAllCaps(false);
```

Comment: @Henry Zhu, See the above answer.

Comment: getButton() not available in AlertDialog

Comment: @KamrujjamanJoy Are you using `androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog`? If so, it should be.

Answer (score 3):

Use the DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE or DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE to customize the action buttons.

```
    val builder = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireContext())
    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.alert_title))
    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.alert_msg))
    builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.action_yes)) { _, _ ->
        // todo: your action
    }
    builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.action_no), null)
    val dialog = builder.create()
    dialog.show()
    dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).isAllCaps = false
    dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).isAllCaps = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Or even :

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
```

For the basic usage.

Answer (score 0):

using androidx.appcompat.app.AalertDialog fixed for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

its late, but it could help other who visits.

To change the button text case, from all capitals to small case, usual method such as

> `dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setAllCaps(false);`

this will not work with the alert builder anymore, upon exploring alert dialog code, I found Buttons used for it, and as default it will show capital text.

To set, we need to add style while creating the alert dialog. Follow below steps for the same.

1. In your theme.xml or style.xml add below style.

> ```
> <style name="custom_alert_button_text" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog.Alert">
>         <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
>         <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/_13ssp</item>
>         <item name="android:textAppearance">?textAppearanceFiraSansBoldBlue34Text</item>
> </style>
> ```

2. While building the alert dialog, add style to your alert dialog as follow.

> ```
> val alertBox = AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.custom_alert_button_text)
>         alertBox.setCancelable(false)
>         alertBox.setMessage("Your message for dialog")
>         alertBox.setNegativeButton(
>             "No"
>         ) { dialog, _ ->
>             dialog.dismiss()
>         }
>         alertBox.setPositiveButton(
>             "Yes"
>         ) { dialog, _ ->
>             dialog.dismiss()
>             //your action to perform on yes tap.
>         }
>         alertBox.show()
> ```

This way, the positive and negative buttons text cases can be changed.

I am using this method to change the text cases for alert dialog with builder.

Hope it helps!